# Is it possible to find closeness centrality using Gephi?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, gephi

I'm a newbie to Gephi. I need to calculate the centrality measures. Is there an option/plugin available to calculate them ?

Answer (score 2):

In the "Statistics" Panel, find the "Network Diameter" metrics. Click on "Run" next to it.

This computes centrality measures for each node, and they can be seen in the "Data Laboratory" view in Gephi.